# AudioRecord buffer size

Tags: android, audiorecord

I initialize my AudioRecord instance as follows:

```
// TODO: remember to add RECORD_AUDIO permission
int audioSource = MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC;

// TODO: I should consider Nyquist frequency and tell the user if her device can correctly detect frequencies in the range of her instrument
int sampleRateInHz = getDeviceSampleRate(context);

int channelConfig = AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO;
int audioFormat = AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT;

// TODO: bufferSizeInBytes should be set according to minimum detectable frequency in order to have at least three periods
int bufferSizeInBytes = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(sampleRateInHz, channelConfig, audioFormat);

AudioRecord audioRecord = new AudioRecord(audioSource, sampleRateInHz, channelConfig, audioFormat, bufferSizeInBytes);
```

Here are my questions:

- I have to read shorts from the buffer because I specified `ENCODING_PCM_16BIT`. Is it correct?
- If minimum buffer size in bytes is 1000 I'll have 500 shorts. So if I need 4096 samples I have to set bufferSizeInBytes to 8192. Is it correct?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I have to read shorts from the buffer because I specified `ENCODING_PCM_16BIT`. Is it correct?

You should, but you don't necessarily have to. You may read the samples into a `byte[]`, but it's up to you to handle the endianness when converting the `byte`s to `short`s.

> If minimum buffer size in bytes is 1000 I'll have 500 shorts. So if I need 4096 samples I have to set bufferSizeInBytes to 8192. Is it correct?

Actually, no.

The minimum buffer size is the very minimum size that an `AudioRecord` instance will accept. It's like a threshold. [`AudioRecord` constructor documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioRecord.html#AudioRecord(int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int)) says:

> Using values smaller than getMinBufferSize() will result in an initialization failure.

In some cases you may want to use a buffer size bigger than the minimum. [`AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize()` documentation`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioRecord.html#getMinBufferSize(int,%20int,%20int)) says:

> Note that this size doesn't guarantee a smooth recording under load, and higher values should be chosen according to the expected frequency at which the AudioRecord instance will be polled for new data.

Here's an algorithm for reading 4096 16-bit samples:

```java
ByteArrayOutputStream mainBuffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

int minimumBufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(...);

byte[] readBuffer = new byte[minimumBufferSize];

AudioRecord recorder = new AudioRecord(..., minimumBufferSize);

recorder.startRecording();

while (mainBuffer.size() < 8192) {

    // read() is a blocking call
    int bytesRead = recorder.read(readBuffer, 0, minimumBufferSize);

    mainBuffer.write(readBuffer, 0, bytesRead);
}

recorder.stop();

recorder.release();
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply. "Data should be read from the audio hardware in chunks of sizes inferior to the total recording buffer size." ([AudioRecord](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioRecord.html)). So, if I need to analyze 4096 samples and I know that I'm going to read shorts, I have to initialize my AudioRecord instance using a `bufferSizeInBytes` of 8192 units. Is it correct?

Comment: Why do I have to implement the algo you posted? If I call `AudioRecord#read`, the operation will block until all samples are read. Is it correct?

Comment: @AdrianoDiGiovanni i think 8192 is too big for `bufferSizeInBytes`. I would create an `AudioRecord` with `getMinBufferSize()` or a few multiples of it

Comment: Why too big? I don't care about latency nor responsiveness: it's a guitar tuner and recording/analysis is performed in a background task. Any other criteria?

Comment: @AdrianoDiGiovanni that algo is not mandatory, of course. Yes, `read()` is a blocking call

Comment: @AdrianoDiGiovanni take a look at the `read()` doc. The point is that `read()` don't necessarily returns all the samples you need in a single call. It may return less samples. So it is recommended that you read samples until you have enough